# Load two jqgrids in order ( sequence ajax calls)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I have two `jqgrids` in my page. when page load i will popup a `modeldialogwindow` to the user that use a `ajax` call. i will populate jqgrids by using the value from the popup window that user selected. can i delay the `jqgrid` load ajax calls ? ( by giving `timeout`?)my issue is sometimes grids `ajax` calls fires before the popup. so that from the back end it will throw an error. ( since the value that user select is not exists. i need to do the following in a sequence manner.

1. show the popup window . wait for user response( this will automatically happens when using the `window.showModalDialog`) get the value that user selects and post to back end.
2. send ajax call to load the first grid.
3. send ajax call to load the second grid.

since jqgrids are populating just after the `'$(document).ready'` i was unable to delay it.

appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should set `datatype` parameter of the both grids to `'local'` at the initialization. It will prevent any `ajax` calls. After the user select all parameters needed for the `ajax` request you should set the `datatype` to `'json'` (or `'xml'` depend on your requirements) and trigger `reloadGrid`:

```
$("#list").setGridParam({datatype:'json',page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Comment: Thanks again oleg. i got this solved. by setting the initial datatype to 'local'. appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the jqgrid function on $(document).ready move it to an event that gets fired after the user makes a selection in the modal box.

Comment: @dik_is - thank you very much for the response d1k. i used your approach but encountered some issues. appreciate your help.